# C# dataReader not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, datareader

I am trying to take a single value from a database, but the cycle does not seem to start at all?

```
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                value = dataReader["amount"].ToString();
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

These are the commands:

```
 public string value; 
    public static string Konekcija = "Server=127.0.0.1; Database=CardIgrica; Uid=admin; Pwd=admin;";
    public string komanda = "SELECT amount FROM CardIgrica.creaures WHERE id = '1';";
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Konekcija);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(komanda, connection);
connection.Open();
```

Comment: What happens if you run the query on its own directly in the database?

Comment: Isn´t id an integer in your database? Right now you are using it as a varchar/nvarchar.

Comment: Does the code enter the while loop?

Comment: Is there actually a row with the `id` of `'1'` (or `1`, which is not the same thing)?

Answer (score 0):

try this for the select

```
public string value {get; set;}
string komanda ="SELECT amount FROM CardIgrica.creaures WHERE id = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

First open your sql connection then make object of MySqlCommand like below:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Konekcija);

connection.Open();


MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(komanda, connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Konekcija))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.CommandText = komanda ;
        conn.Open();
        var dataReader= cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (result.Read())
        {
          value = dataReader["amount"].ToString();
        }


        conn.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need single value, you can use `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` instead of `cmd.ExecuteReader();`
because `ExecuteScalar()` will return single value.